# Excel mortgage calculator with extra payments: How to get payoff date without full amortization table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate how much faster I will pay off a mortgage if I make extra payments toward principal every month. There are plenty of amortization sheets floating around that I can use to produce a full amortization table, with the bottom row showing me the date of the last payment.

What I need is a formula that will give me only that: just that date, or alternatively, the number of months it will take me to pay off the loan given: Rate, principal, term in years, extra amount I will pay monthly, and start date.

Help, I can't figure this one out!

Comment: Late comment but: Can you post your attempts at doing this? What have you done so far to achieve this goal? This site is not a free scripting service. The community here helps those who help themselves. So if you have attempted to do something to achieve this goal, please post your code/script/formula and the community can attempt to help you. As it stands this question reads as a free scripting request and will most likely be closed as a result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some formula to help you:

- yearly rate, principal, original term: input parameters
- original term (in months): `= B4 * 12`
- original monthly payback amount: `=PMT(B2/12,B4*12,B3)`
- extra payment starting from Nth month: input
- balance before first extra payment: `=-FV(B2/12,B8-1,B6,B3)`
- new total term in months: `=NPER(B2/12,B6+B7,B9)+B8-1`

[image]